# SQL query (in MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with potentially very many records (above 1 million) that contains simple data along with a timestamp that holds the moment of registration (defining CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value for that field).

I want to implement a simple query that scans the table only once and counts the number of records that were register, say, the last 24 hours, the last 7 days and the last month.

Was trying this with no results (getting all zeros though I should get few **1**'s for sure):

```
SET @1 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ;
SET @2 = @1 - INTERVAL 24 HOUR ;
SET @3 = @1 - INTERVAL  7 DAY  ;
SET @4 = @1 - INTERVAL  1 MONTH;

select Registration_Timestamp , (case Registration_Timestamp when  Registration_Timestamp> @2 THEN 1 else 0 end) as LAST_DAY  ,
                                (case Registration_Timestamp when  Registration_Timestamp> @3 THEN 1 else 0 end) as LAST_WEEK ,
                                (case Registration_Timestamp when  Registration_Timestamp> @4 THEN 1 else 0 end) as LAST_MONTH  
 from tbl_Dummy 
where Registration_Timestamp >= @4 ;
```

This is not going to give the sum of course, but once I get this to show `1`s I will wrap it with  `select count(LAST_DAY),count(LAST_WEEK),count(LAST_MONTH)` which will do the job of course.

Where is my error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` statements are slightly out:

```
 CASE *expr1* 
    WHEN *expr2* THEN *expr3*
    ELSE 0 
 END
```

Compares `expr1` to `expr2` and returns `expr3` when `expr1 = expr2`

Your first `CASE` actually compares `Registration_Timestamp` (a timestamp) to the result of `Registration_Timestamp> @2` (1 for true, 0 for false) which isn't what you want.

You want this form of `CASE`:

```
CASE  
    WHEN *expr1* THEN *expr2*
    ELSE 0 
END
```

Which returns `expr2` when `expr1` is true

In your first `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN Registration_Timestamp > @2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**Alternatively**

MySQL actually returns 1 and 0 already for conditionals. It's not hugely portable but you could use:

```
SELECT Registration_Timestamp > @2 AS LAST_DAY
```

**Note**

`COUNT(*expr*)` will count 1 for every `NOT NULL` result, which will count 1s and 0s the same, so you'd need `SUM()` here.

Or you could change your `CASE`s to:

```
CASE WHEN Registration_Timestamp > @2 THEN 1 END
```

Which will return `NULL` when the condition is not met.

Comment: Of course!!!! Stupid me!!! Thank you man!!!! The `CASE WHEN Registration_Timestamp > @2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is best of course.

Comment: @FDavidov No problem, happy to help. Please upvote/accept the answer if you found it useful or correct! :)

Comment: Thanks again @Arth. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the case statement. Just select the boolean expression directly and you will get the results you are looking for.

```
/*My Test Data*/

INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 26 HOUR);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 DAY);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 8 DAY);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 29 DAY);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
INSERT INTO regtable(RegDate) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH);


/* My SQL */
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() into @ts;

select Id, RegDate, 
       RegDate > @ts - INTERVAL 24 HOUR as LAST_DAY,
       RegDate > @ts - INTERVAL 7 DAY as LAST_WEEK,
       RegDate > @ts - INTERVAL 1 MONTH as LAST_MONTH
  from regtable
 WHERE RegDate >= @ts - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

**RESULTS**

```
Id  RegDate                LAST_DAY LAST_WEEK LAST_MONTH
 1  2016-05-17 04:13:29     1        1         1
11  2016-05-16 16:13:30     0        1         1
21  2016-05-16 14:13:30     0        1         1
31  2016-05-12 16:13:30     0        1         1
41  2016-05-10 16:13:30     0        0         1
51  2016-05-09 16:13:30     0        0         1
61  2016-04-18 16:13:30     0        0         1
```

Comment: Also very nice indeed, but I prefer Arth's suggestion for portability reasons (I thing that Oracle, for instance, would not return 1 and 0 (I'm not 100% sure though). Many thanks anyway.

Comment: The case statements result in branching in the CPU. You shouldn't add case statements when they are not needed.